# Проблема c Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
ruby -v
ruby 2.1.5p273 (2014-11-13) [x86_64-linux-gnu]

gem -v
2.5.1

rails -v
/usr/local/lib/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require': cannot load such file -- bundler/setup (LoadError)
from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
from /home/user/WebProject/demo/config/boot.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
from bin/rails:3:in `require_relative'
from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
```

Когда ставлю через `gem install rails`, вот что пишет в консоли:

```
gem install rails  
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...  
ERROR:  Error installing rails:  
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.  

current directory: /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.7.2/ext/nokogiri
/usr/bin/ruby2.1 -r ./siteconf20160129-8816-dcz7op.rb extconf.rb  
checking if the C compiler accepts ... yes  
Building nokogiri using packaged libraries.  
Using mini_portile version 2.0.0  
checking for gzdopen() in -lz... no  
zlib is missing; necessary for building libxml2  
*** extconf.rb failed ***  
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:  
    --with-opt-dir  
    --without-opt-dir  
    --with-opt-include  
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include  
    --with-opt-lib  
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib  
    --with-make-prog  
    --without-make-prog   
    --srcdir=.  
    --curdir  
    --ruby=/usr/bin/ruby2.1  
    --help  
    --clean  
    --use-system-libraries  
    --enable-static  
    --disable-static  
    --with-zlib-dir  
    --without-zlib-dir   
    --with-zlib-include  
    --without-zlib-include=${zlib-dir}/include  
    --with-zlib-lib   
    --without-zlib-lib=${zlib-dir}/lib  
    --enable-cross-build  
    --disable-cross-build  

To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can be found here:  

  /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.1.0/nokogiri-1.6.7.2/mkmf.log  

extconf failed, exit code 1  

Gem files will remain installed in /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.7.2 for inspection.  
Results logged to /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.1.0/nokogiri-1.6.7.2/gem_make.out
```

Но если делать новый проект `rails new demo`, то каркас ставится, все нормально, а потом пытаюсь запустить `rails server` в корне папки `demo`, то выдает

```
rails server
/usr/local/lib/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in   `require': cannot load such file -- bundler/setup (LoadError)   
    from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext  /kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'  
    from /home/user/WebProject/demo/config/boot.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'  
    from bin/rails:3:in `require_relative'  
    from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Какая у вас ОС?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всё в логах:

```
zlib is missing; necessary for building libxml2
```

Установите пакет библиотеки `zlib` для разработки (в Debian и производных — это пакет `zlib1g-dev`).